# What does $h$ and $x$ represent in $2x+h$

Tags: average

I was asked to find the average gradient between $x=2$ and $x=5$ on the curve $y=x^2+3$.

My method:

Average gradient = $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$
$$=\frac{x^2+2xh+h^2+3-(x^2+3)}{h}$$
$$=\frac{h^2+2xh}{h}$$
$$ = 2x+h$$

What must I put in place of x? $5$ or $2$? and what must I put for the $h$ value? And **why**? Please help.

Note: Please do not give alternative solutions. Just elaborate on mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want $h=(5-2)=3$, $x=2$.  This is so that $x+h=5$.

For average gradient one usually prefers the formula $$\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$$
which makes it clear that

$$\frac{5^2+3-2^2-3}{5-2} =\frac{28-7}{3}=\frac{21}{3}=7$$